# How to access same usecase inside multiple feature modules

Tags: android, use-case, clean-architecture, dynamic-feature-module

in the case of real large project, i have decided to use clean architecure inside each feature module of my application separately, preventing to have one Giant domain and data layer against too many features.
Now , I'm thinking how to do bestEffort for my issue : if some usecases (like accessing UserInfo) may needed by several feature modules , how to prevent duplicating of creating same domain and data class ?

P.S : I myself decided to have shared-modules for domain and data , which present usecases needed by multipke features. but in this way, there is no boundary or some rules that team mates could understand the specefic usecase is available inside shared-moudle.

modules in project :

- app
- common
- features

  -login

  ```
      -domain


      -data


      -ui
  ```

  -charge

  ```
      -domain


      -data

      -ui
  ```

...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For erveryone reading this ,I decided to package my these common usecases( like everything related to user infomation , such as userinfo ) into another common module named `UserModule` Which has its own data and domain module without any presentation module.
Other modules that may need userInfo can implement this module , so they can have their own clean arch with `domain` , `data` , `presentation` based on their need , or have only the `presentation` layer

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).